# Submitting edits to OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, editing

What is the preferred method to submit edits to the OpenStreetMap (OSM) project?

I have read up on a few options but prefer the easiest.

Actually any info on the process would helpful and the main goal is to add missing roads and correct incorrect street names (US Town) on a very infrequent basis.

Comment: The fastest way is to sign up/in to https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=5/51.500/-0.100 and click edit.

Comment: You might also checkout OSM [notes feature](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Notes) if you just want to submit minor fixes from time to time.

Answer (score 4):

OSM editors are listed on this page: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Editors. Most people use one of the "Top Three" listed there--iD, Potlatch 2, or JOSM--but there are many other options.

If all you're doing is adding roads and correcting names, iD or Potlatch 2 would easily meet your needs. iD is the default on osm.org and more beginner-friendly, so that might be the best option for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found this video to show how to edit
https://youtu.be/0H3trF068zw
It show how to merge and use the circle tool to.
It uses the ID editor